# Squid releasing CSS files unnecessarily

Tags: squid

The setup I have has Firefox talking to a web server with Squid being a caching proxy.

Firefox <--> Squid (ssl_bump) <--> Web server

While images (even on https) are cached and do see cache hits, most of the CSS and JavaScript files get cached and get released:

```
1367165735.552 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF 0CF738871B9B86A15838CE1BE65BEE8E  200 1367165735        -1 1367265735 x-squid-internal/vary -1/0 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/1.6/dijit/form/Button.xd.js
1367165735.552 RELEASE 00 00000179 532661AE3C1B87904B52AC3FB1B9F971  200 1367165718 1333798649        -1 application/x-javascript 2495/2495 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/1.6/dijit/form/Button.xd.js
1367165735.552 SWAPOUT 00 00000192 128BF66F1EB8A67509CC774E3DFB50DC  200 1367165734 1333798649        -1 application/x-javascript 2495/2495 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/1.6/dijit/form/Button.xd.js
1367165737.268 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF 184B43B9627622DA2CC2415794961437  200 1367165737        -1 1367265737 x-squid-internal/vary -1/0 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/themes/tundra.css
1367165737.268 RELEASE 00 0000017D F5692CC660A0F4BA4FEDC211275BA0E4  200 1367165720 1366120055        -1 text/css 14723/14723 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/themes/tundra.css
1367165737.268 SWAPOUT 00 00000193 D1D0E32C07C74BF2D4F235EFEAC33DE1  200 1367165736 1366120055        -1 text/css 14723/14723 GET https://9.123.122.180/common/js/dojo/themes/tundra.css
```

I tried playing with the switches in the config file, but nothing seems to be working.

```
offline_mode on
vary_ignore_expire on
reply_header_access Last-Modified deny all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since deny all
request_header_access Cache-Control deny all
```

Is there some other flag/setting that can prevent those unnecessary RELEASES? How do I debug it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've temporarily ended up doing is that I modified HttpHeader.cc in squid's src directory to turn a blind eye to the "Vary" header.

Original line:

```
  {"Vary", HDR_VARY, ftStr},       /* for now */
```

My workaround:

```
  {"Vary-junk", HDR_VARY, ftStr},       /* for now */
```

But yes, this is a crude hack that's grossly unsuitable for anything other than temporary testing. Hopefully there's a better way out.